# optimize python counting in a three-iteration statement

Tags: python

all,

I try to count the number of items that meet the following conditions
house id==m and transformed day segment id == n and neighborhood function == m
where house ids are represented by docs['house_id'], day segment ids are represented by docs['transformed_dayseg_id'], and neighborhood functions are represented by self.CF/self.TF/self.BF.

For this purpose, I perform counting in terms of the following codes. However, it is too slow. Any idea about optimizing the python counting codes?

```
def get_mnf_counter(self, docs, dtype):
    x = np.zeros((self.M,self.N,self.K))
    for m in range(self.M):
        for n in range(self.N):
            for k in range(self.K):
                if dtype==1: #checkin
                    x[m, n, k]=sum((np.array(docs['house_id'])==m) & (np.array(docs['transformed_dayseg_id'])==n) & (self.CF==k))
                elif dtype==2: #taxi
                    x[m, n, k]=sum((np.array(docs['house_id'])==m) & (np.array(docs['transformed_dayseg_id'])==n) & (self.TF==k))
                elif dtpe==3: #bus
                    x[m, n, k]=sum((np.array(docs['house_id'])==m) & (np.array(docs['transformed_dayseg_id'])==n) & (self.BF==k))
                else:
                    raise Exception("index of checkin/taxi/bus/ is wrong")
    return x
```

Comment: Can you please provide more details, mentioned in the [Sebastian's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27674353/optimize-python-counting-in-a-three-iteration-statement/27674375?noredirect=1#comment43764467_27674375)?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `itertools.product`, like this

```
from itertools import product
...
...

for m, n, k in product(range(self.M), range(self.N), range(self.K)):
   ...
```

More good news is, you can optimize your code even more, like this

```
from itertools import product
def get_mnf_counter(self, docs, dtype):
    x = np.zeros((self.M, self.N, self.K))

    if dtype not in (1, 2, 3):
        raise Exception("index of checkin/taxi/bus/ is wrong")

    if dtype == 1:
        value = self.CF
    elif dtype == 2:
        value = self.TF
    else:
        value = self.BF

    house_id = np.array(docs['house_id'])
    dayseg_id = np.array(docs['transformed_dayseg_id'])

    for m, n, k in product(range(self.M), range(self.N), range(self.K)):
        x[m, n, k] = sum((house_id == m) & (dayseg_id == n) & (value == k))
```

Since your algorithm is O(N ^ 3), there is nothing much you can do here.

Comment: That's certainly nicer, but is it faster?

Comment: @IsmailBadawi You can always `timeit` :-)

Comment: you could use `count_nonzero()` instead of `sum()` (`dtype=bool`). And/Or vectorize the operations e.g., `np.arange(self.K, dtype=int) & value)` instead of `value == k`.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Actually I am not familiar with numpy :'(

Comment: @thefourtheye then you should know that simple indexing is *very* slow for numpy arrays.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Yup, but I couldn't come up with a better solution. Can you please make your comment an answer?

Comment: I don't want to write "more efficient" code without a benchmark. It is not clear what is the order of magnitude of the input values here. Your code seems readable and correct. OP should provide example input data and the performance goal (how fast is fast enough)